# How to properly do conditional aggregation in Hive

Tags: hive, aggregation

Assume I have this data:

```
player_id  stats
100        [{"position":"offense","wins":35},{"position":"defense","wins":17}]
200        [{"position":"offense","wins":85},{"position":"defense","wins":52}]
300        [{"position":"offense","wins":12},{"position":"defense","wins":98}]
```

And I want to display it as such:

```
player_id  offense_wins  defense_wins
100        35            17
200        85            52
300        12            98
```

The original data above is currently thrown into an ORC table using:

```
SELECT p.player_id
     , s.position
     , s.wins
FROM player_stats p
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(p.stats) sTable as s
```

Which gets me:

```
player_id  position  wins
100        offense   35
100        defense   17
200        offense   85
200        defense   52
300        offense   12
300        defense   98
```

Now from this point in MySQL I can just group_by the player_id then case the position, pulling in the associated wins value when it = 'offense' or 'defense' into their own columns, then wrap each case in a COALESCE() to prevent the nulls from coming through.  Super fast.

In Hive, instead of COALESCE I have to use MIN or MAX, but the result will be the same regardless.

Here would be the primary way this data is queried:

```
SELECT player_id
     , max(case when position = 'offense' then wins end) as offense_wins
     , max(case when position = 'defense' then wins end) as defense_wins
FROM orctable
WHERE player_id = 100
GROUP BY player_id
```

Which would result in :

```
player_id  offense_wins  defense_wins
100        35            17
```

Now, in my real world situation the original dataset has six instances of that 'stats' array, each containing a map of 3-5 pairs.  Because of this, the ORC table has player_id listed some 700 times from the repeated lateral views.

The entire table is 300k rows, and the player_id in the real world example is duplicated on this table just over 700 times.

**Question 1** - is this the only and/or proper way to transform the data into the desired end result?
**Question 2** - should this query be taking between 5 and 10 seconds to complete?  The same dataset on a small MySQL server would do this in milliseconds.